# Apple MacBook 13-inch mid-2010, 4gb RAM, 250 Gb HDD: Can I dual Boot to Windows 10?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, bootcamp, memory

I'd like to put a larger hdd into this macbook, and then install Windows 10 onto it. Has Anybody successfully updated their Mac-based Wintel install with Windows 10, and what is involved?

I realize this is probably a stretch, but I love making things work that should not. Half the time I boot this MacBook with my Tails Linux bootable DVD and run securely - perfect for coffeeshops, etc, as the MacBook's internal drive isn't even mounted so there's no way a dirty prankster can get their mitts on my data!

Anyway, I'd appreciate any advice or suggestions, but please refrain from responding if all you plan to do is deride me for  wanting to do what I want to do. Constructive criticism welcome, insults are not!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201468). It clearly describes all steps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do but install at your own risk until Apple issues an update for Boot Camp.

Assuming you have the Windows 10 ISO run the bootcamp and follow the standard procedure.

Make sure you allocated minimum 20 GB, 30 or more is better.

It might take over a hour to complete.